# How to call generics in a nested class

Tags: java

I have a class nested inside another class, and I am having some problems with generics

```
public class LinkedListDeque<unknown_type> {
    private class Link {
        public Link start;
        public unknown_type body;
        public Link end;
        public Link(Link s, unknown_type b, Link e){
            start = s;
            body = b;
            end = e;
        }
    }
    private Link connection;
    public Link(){
        connection = new Link(null, 1, null)
    }
```

When I am trying to construct the connection like this, it will return an error because 1 is an integer rather an unknown_type. Then I tried something like connection = new Link(null, 1, null), which also results in an error. What should I do here?

Comment: I'm uncliear on what you are trying to do.  Why make a node with a type of `int` in a generic linked list?

Comment: You know that you can't use primitive types in java generics, right? Instead of using primitive _int_ you should use wrapper class _Integer_.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I am trying to put a random fixed value in the body of connection, the integer 1 is just randomly chosen.  It does not have to be an integer, but I need to put something in there. @markspace

Comment: @Adam Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have, if possible as a [mcve]. Fix the indentation of your source code to see which blocks is defined in which location.

Answer (score 1):

```
        connection = new LinkedListDeque().new Link(null, 1, null);
```

The problem is not Generics! Your problem was accessing inner class without outer class. So First you have to call new LinkedListDeque()....

Comment: But I have another function below public void addFirst(unknown_type T){
        sentinel.start = new Link(sentinel, T, sentinel.start);
        size += 1;
    }, and it does not have any errors.

Comment: Do you maybe have any idea why?

Comment: I dont know man, I know every single detail about generics but I couldn't figure your code out . Could you please post the whole class?